# Imread single image file using wildcard MatLab

Tags: matlab, wildcard, filepath, imread

I have a bunch of images in a folder and they are indexed. 
Eg:

```
01_Cat.jpg 
02_Dog.jpg
```

and so on. Now, I want to read an image, but I don't want to give the full image name. Is it possible to read an image by using wildcards like below

```
A = imread('01_*.jpg');
B = imread('02_*.jpg');
```

This is not working. MatLab is taking `*` it literally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the use of wildcards is not supported in `imread`, however you can work around it using the `dir` function as follows:

```
A = imread(getfield(dir('01_*.jpg'),'name'));
B = imread(getfield(dir('02_*.jpg'),'name'));
```

Comment: Or directly create a list of all jpgs. with dir('*.jpg') and then loop over the results:

    files = dir('*.jpg');
    for f = files'
      img = imread(f.name);
      %do something  
    end

Comment: Yeah, that's the alternative, although it should be `dir('*.jpg')` rather than `dir('.jpg')`.
I just wanted to show OP how he can use his syntax to achieve the desired output.

Comment: Worked! I have one more problem. The image file is not in current directory. I'm giving the path to the `dir` function. But the getfield function returns only the name of the image. So, currently I'm appending the path to the value returned by `getfield`. Is there any direct way to get the full path as well?

Comment: You can use [fullfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) combining `getfield` with `folder` and `getfield` with `name`.

Comment: Thanks! I used  `dir.('folder')` and `dir.('name')` instead of `getfield(dir, 'name')`. MatLab suggested that.